# Not suitable question going to be removed, what about good answers to this question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I do not have a lot of answers, I can be proud of, and one of them is to the question which is not a good fit for SO. The [question is going to be removed soon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/728260/1090562), but nonetheless the question is not good for SO (also it touches an important topic), I think that my answer is.

I specifically has not directly answered the question, but rather wrote a modern reason why the step of minification of HTML should be (what can you gain from it, why it was neglected and how to do this). Also in my answer I briefly suggested a tool (the tool is not so important).

So my question is: what can I do to preserve the answer to a question which is going to be removed?

Comment: Maybe that question deserves a [hitorical lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) given its relative popularity in views and votes.

Comment: Nevermind, it's already deleted. Gotta love the Streisand effect of meta...

Comment: If you make the better question it may be possible to ask for your answer to be migrated over to it. I don't know how agreeable mods would be to that request but it seems reasonable...

Comment: Maybe I've missed something, but when you said "*The question is going to be removed soon*", how did you find out it would be deleted? Were there already a number of delete votes before you asked this question on Meta?

Comment: @CodeCaster Unfortunately, historical locks are probably the worst kind of closure (due to the way they are implemented): you can't comment, vote or edit. This can be worse than deletion when the information is inaccurate. If we consider SO as a repository of programming knowledge and all that, historical locks are as bad as it gets. Perhaps they should work differently, simply indicating that the question as "we don't want that sort of question any longer", but leaving them more normally open.

Comment: You can ask a new question (that doesn't ask for links to tools) which would be answerable by your question...

Comment: @bruno I saw that there were 8 votes to delete. It takes 10. So most probably soon.

Comment: I just cast the final undelete vote if that makes you feel better. That done, I think adding a new question and pulling that answer over would be better.

Answer (score 27):

Create a better SO question and paste your answer to it?

Not ideal, but I think if you want to save your answer, it's your safest bet.

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing wrong with self-answering a question.  It's even an option on the "Ask Question" page.  I would suggest leaving a comment or footnote as to why it was immediately self-answered though, since some people will downvote because of that if there wasn't a reason given (that is, their thinking is along the lines of "you didn't have an actual problem")

Comment: Look into asking a question about the benefits of minifying HTML/CSS/etc. on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). I think—but won't be held liable—that it would be more on-topic there than Stack Overflow. Phrase the question somewhat generally, but avoid making it a poll. Ask about *specific benefits*, and some guidelines on how you can make the decision. Then post your answer there, if you want. @salv